# AngularJS nesting $http calls

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to write a factory that gets data from two sources and uses one source to expand the data in the other object.

```
app.factory('information', ['$http', '$q', 'players', 'matches', function($http, $q, players, matches) {
    return {
        // Returns all matches and players including extra parsing
        get: function() {
            return players.get().success(function(data) {
                players = data;

                matches.get().success(function(data) {
                    matches = data;

                    for ( match in matches ) {
                        matches[match].a_player1 = players.filter(function(player) { return player.username == matches[match].a_player1 })[0];
                        matches[match].a_player2 = players.filter(function(player) { return player.username == matches[match].a_player2 })[0];
                        matches[match].b_player1 = players.filter(function(player) { return player.username == matches[match].b_player1 })[0];
                        matches[match].b_player2 = players.filter(function(player) { return player.username == matches[match].b_player2 })[0];
                        console.log(matches)
                    }

                    return matches;
                });
            });
        },
    }
}]);
```

Both `matches.get()` and `players.get()` are simple `GET`requests to an API like so:

```
app.factory('players', function($http) {
    return {
        get: function() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/players',
            });
        },
    }
});
```

But the above code (of course) returns the `players` object while I want it to return the `matches` object after it gets combined with the `players` object.

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That function won't return anything since you can't directly return a value from an async operation, either return the promise or use a callback. But I think what you're looking for is `$q.all`:

```
return {
        // Returns all matches and players including extra parsing
        getEverything: function() {

        var getPlayers= $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/players',
        });
        var getMatches= $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/matches',
        });

           return $q.all([getPlayers,getMatches]);
        }
}
```

Usage:

```
getEverything().then(function(data){
   var players=data[0].data;
   var matches=data[1].data;
})
```

EDIT:

Irrelevant, but to move this back in the factory:

```
getEverything: function() {
            var getPlayers= $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/players',
            });
            var getMatches= $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/matches',
            });
            return $q.all([getPlayers,getMatches]);
},
getEverythingMapped:function(){
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 this.getEverything().then(function(data){
       var players=data[0].data;
       var matches=data[1].data;
//do as many loops on either result set as you like
                for ( match in matches ) {
                    matches[match].a_player1 = players.filter(function(player) { return   player.username == matches[match].a_player1 })[0];
                    matches[match].a_player2 = players.filter(function(player) { return player.username == matches[match].a_player2 })[0];
                    matches[match].b_player1 = players.filter(function(player) { return player.username == matches[match].b_player1 })[0];
                    matches[match].b_player2 = players.filter(function(player) { return player.username == matches[match].b_player2 })[0];
                    console.log(matches)
//use of a promise here allows us top use this method using -then, we need to so this since we're
//waiting for the result of an async server call before we can loop through players and matches
                     deferred.resolve(matches);
                }


 }
}
```

Now you would use the above method like this in your controller:

```
information.getEverythingMapped().then(function(matches){
 console.log(matches);
})
```

Comment: But then where would I parse my data (the `for in` loop)?

Comment: Anywhere. What I wrote is just a blueprint, you could put the for loop after the service call, after `var matches=data[1].data;`

Comment: In this particular example, since there is no dependency on two GET calls, $q is a better option. Nested $http when you have dependencies.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. In order to parse the `matches` object I need to be sure that the `$http` request already finished because I need the `players` object for additional information and I want to parse it inside the factory because I want to be able to use it in multiple controllers.

Comment: @CasCornelissen I understood your question :) You have both those result sets available after `var players=data[0].data;var matches=data[1].data;` So you can do whatever you like with the. You can also move this code back into your factory, whats the problem????

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea how to move the `for in` loop into my factory...

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs for [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), this service returns a promise. So no need for the $q service in this case it can be simply written like this:

```
app.factory('information', ['$http', 'players', 'matches', function($http, players, matches) {
    return {
        // Returns all matches and players including extra parsing
        get: function(callback) {
            players.get().then(function(playersData) {
                matches.get().then(function(matchesData) {
                    matches = matchesData;
                    players = playersData;
                    for ( match in matches ) {
                        matches[match].a_player1 = players.filter(function(player) { return player.username == matches[match].a_player1 })[0];
                        matches[match].a_player2 = players.filter(function(player) { return player.username == matches[match].a_player2 })[0];
                        matches[match].b_player1 = players.filter(function(player) { return player.username == matches[match].b_player1 })[0];
                        matches[match].b_player2 = players.filter(function(player) { return player.username == matches[match].b_player2 })[0];
                        console.log(matches)
                    }
                    callback(matches);
                });
            });
        },
    }
}]);
```

and in the controller call information like this:

```
information.get(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I tried that already but it keeps returning a `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Error maybe in something else then, have you put consoles for matches and players and checked the values coming?

Comment: It's definitely the get function and I think it happens because it doesn't return anything directly. I can't call it like `information.get().succes(function() { ... } )` either, because it doesn't return a promise. And calling `console.log(information.get())` returns undefined, which matches my hypothesis.

Comment: @CasCornelissen: updated the code to have a callback inorder to return the matches when everything is done. This callback can be used as shown in the controller which is consuming the information factory

Comment: I'm still getting the `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. When trying `console.log(information)` it returns the correct object with the `get` function, and in `<function scope>.Closure` there's `matches` and `players` including the correct data. But when trying `console.log(information.get())` it returns undefined.

Comment: information.get() now has a parameter for callback. have you tried to put a console just like what I have written in the answer?

Comment: Very hard to understand why you getting this error as everything appears to be fine. Can you come up with a plunkr for this problem. You can create JSON files in order to replicate your factory calls for matches and players